# Where to declare object with shared partial form in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have a text_area form to create a quick `Idea` object. This form appears on many parts of the site so I move it as a `shared/_idea_form.html.haml` file.

I'm currently defining the new object in every controller action where the form is present with `@ideas = Idea.new` to make it work.

Is there a more convenient/global way define the `@ideas = Idea.new` outside each action? I.e. as a before_filter in the application controller. I'm not sure if that would be the right approach to this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can put it directly in view

```
  <%= form_for @idea ||= Idea.new do |f| %>
     #your text area
    <%end%>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have it on most of the actions yes, that should be a good way. If was me in your place I think I would brake the rules and would do that in the partial... Sometimes rules dosen't make sense and this time is one of it. You just want a form on every page, and so you need to create always a new Idea for the form.. Or do that on the partial or just create the form without helpers.

Just one opinion :)

Answer (score 0):

There are tons of options: using the `decent_exposure` gem ([try it](https://github.com/voxdolo/decent_exposure), it's cool!), using `before_filter`s for setting the value of the `@idea`, manually creating new `Idea` in your form, defining some helper which will provide your form with a prepared `Idea`.

Answer (score 0):

in **app/controllers/application_controller.rb**:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_filter :create_new_idea

  def create_new_idea
    @idea = Idea.new
  end
end
```

That will set `@idea` to a new object on every request.  There must be some cases where you don't want `@idea` set to a new instance or even set at all.  In that case there are a number of options, here's one:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_filter :create_new_idea, lambda {|controller| controller.set_new_idea?}

  def create_new_idea
    @idea = Idea.new
  end

  def set_new_idea?
    # this should be false in some case
  end
end
```